# CSR Sparse Matrix and TruncatedSVD Fit - NLP / Topic Modeling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix, dask

I'm working on a topic modeling project. In this case, I would like to decrease the document matrix's dimensionality using Truncated SVD before applying KMeans.

I've processed (i.e. cleaned, tokenized, lemmatized) and vectorized the raw documents. I've applied a Tf-Idf vectorizer. As an FYI, I've successfully implemented the Tfidf vectorizer with LDA and NMF.

I've tried two approaches:

**FIRST APPROACH**

```
docs_raw = wallstreet['processed_text']
n_topics = 20
max_doc_freq = 0.7
min_doc_freq = 4
max_features = 10000
ngram_rng = [1, 2]
max_iterations = 25

docs_vectorized, vectorizer = nlp_topic_utils.tfidf_vectorizer(docs_raw, min_doc_freq, max_doc_freq, max_features, ngram_rng)

tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=docs_vectorized.shape[1]-1)
docs_tsvd = tsvd.fit(docs_vectorized)
```

This approach resulted in a Memory Error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.38 GiB for an array with shape (45372, 10009) and data type float64
```

Also, I am unclear as to why **docs_vectorized** has 10,009 columns instead of 10,000.

I then attempted to use a Dask array, which is causing an Index Error.

**SECOND APPROACH**

```
import dask.array as da

docs_vectorized, vectorizer = nlp_topic_utils.tfidf_vectorizer(docs_raw, min_doc_freq, max_doc_freq, max_features, ngram_rng)

docs_dask_arr = da.from_array(docs_vectorized, chunks='auto', asarray=True)

tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=docs_dask_arr.shape[1]-1, random_state=random_state)
docs_tsvd = tsvd.fit(docs_dask_arr)
```

The corresponding error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I missing?